# is there no BOM for com.amazonaws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, maven-bom

I’m failry new to AWS developer space.
I’m struggling to find the suitable versions of all required dependencies.

I created a simple lambda with folowwing versions of core and even dependencies

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This all works fine,but now if I want to create a labmda with enough depdendencies, how do I get compatible versions.

We do have bom for aws sdk like below.

```
<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
<artifactId>bom</artifactId>
```

Do we have any BOM for `com.amazonaws` that I can use to have compatible versions of dynammoDb, events & lambda-core ? the  `software.amazon.awssdk:bom` does not have required lambda-core event etc.

Comment: Just the latest version for all, they'll be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are expected to maintain your local BOM.

You should refer to their [readme.md](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs).

Apparently this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/327) was once raised in [aws-lambda-java-libs](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs).